# A* shortest path algorithm optimization

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management, taxicab-geometry

I had this programming exercise of mine where I had to find the shortest path to an exit in an NxM -grid maze in under a second (both N and M would be anywhere between 3 and 1000). The program would be tested with 10 different inputs (mazes), all of which includes a very different amount of exits.

The input goes as follows:

```
7 10
##########
#.....#... <- exit
#.#.###.##
#..X..#..#
#.#.#.#.##
#......... <- exit
###.######
   ^exit
```

Where the first number is height and the second width. The rest is the maze itself, and X marks the (starting) spot.

Well, I solved the problem using the A* algorithm and at the same time keeping track of the nearest exit (simple Manhattan distance). Now what's bugging me is that my fellow programmers have come to a lot faster and more memory-friendly solutions than I. My request is that you guys point out anything that comes to your mind, were it to be a completely different algorithm or just a stupid memory leak.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::vector<int> monovector;
typedef std::vector< std::vector<int> > bivector;

int _abs(int num);
int* get_nearest_goal(int y, int x, bivector &goals_t);
int goals = 0;

void appendClosedList(int y, int x, bivector &openList, bivector &closedList) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < openList.size(); i++)
        if(openList[i][0] == y && openList[i][1] == x) closedList.push_back(openList[i]);
}

void dropOpenList(int y, int x, bivector &openList) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < openList.size(); i++)
        if(openList[i][0] == y && openList[i][1] == x) openList.erase(openList.begin()+i);
}

int* get_coords(bivector &openList)
{
    int* coords = new int[2];
    int min_element = 1000000;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < openList.size(); i++) {
        if(openList[i][2] < min_element) {
            min_element = openList[i][2];
            coords[0] = openList[i][0];
            coords[1] = openList[i][1];
        }
    }
    return coords;
}

struct laby_t {
    int h, w, s_y, s_x;
    char **m_layout;
    int ***m_attr, ***_m_attr;
    int ***m_parent, ***_m_parent;

    laby_t() {
        std::cin >> h >> w;

        m_layout  = new char *[h+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < h+1; i++)
            m_layout[i]  = new char[w+1];

        m_parent = new int **[h];
        m_attr  = new int **[h];
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            m_attr[i]  = new int *[w];
            m_parent[i] = new int *[w];

            std::cin >> m_layout[i];

            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                m_attr[i][j] = new int[4];
                m_parent[i][j] = new int[2];

                m_attr[i][j][0] = 0;
                m_attr[i][j][1] = 0;
                m_parent[i][j][0] = 0;
                m_parent[i][j][1] = 0;
                if(m_layout[i][j] == '#') m_attr[i][j][0] = 2;
                if(m_layout[i][j] == 'X') { s_y = i; s_x = j; }
            }
        }

    }

    int get_visited (int y, int x) { return this->m_attr[y][x][0]; }
    int get_depth(int y, int x)    {
        if(this->m_attr[y][x][1]) return this->m_attr[y][x][1];
        else return 0;
    }
    int get_estimate(int y, int x) { return this->m_attr[y][x][2]; }
    int get_priority(int y, int x) { return this->m_attr[y][x][3]; }

    void set_visited(int py, int px, int y, int x, int f_y, int f_x, int depth)  {
        this->m_attr[y][x][0] = 1; 
        this->m_attr[y][x][1] = depth;
        this->m_attr[y][x][2] = _abs(f_y - y) + _abs(f_x - x);
        this->m_attr[y][x][3] = this->m_attr[y][x][1] + this->m_attr[y][x][2];
        this->m_parent[y][x][0] = py;
        this->m_parent[y][x][1] = px;
    }

    void reset()
    {
        delete this->m_attr;
        delete this->m_parent;
        delete this->m_layout;
    }
};

void dropGoals(int f_y, int f_x, bivector &goals_t, laby_t &laby)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < goals_t.size(); i++)
        if(goals_t[i][0] == f_y && goals_t[i][1] == f_x) {
            goals_t.erase(goals_t.begin()+i);
            laby.m_layout[goals_t[i][0]][goals_t[i][i]] = '#';
            laby.m_attr[goals_t[i][0]][goals_t[i][i]][0] = 2;
        }
}

int wander(int y, int x, int f_y, int f_x, laby_t &laby, bivector goals_t)
{
    int depth = 1;
    laby.set_visited(y, x, y, x, f_y, f_x, depth);
    monovector r; r.push_back(y); r.push_back(x); r.push_back(laby.get_priority(y, x)); r.push_back(0);
    bivector openList, closedList;
    openList.push_back(r);
    r.clear();

    int dir[4][2] = {
                        { 1, 0},
                        {-1, 0},
                        { 0, 1},
                        { 0,-1}
                    };

    while(!(y == f_y && x == f_x))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            int _y = y + dir[i][0];
            int _x = x + dir[i][1];
            if(y > 0 && y < laby.h-1 && x > 0 && x < laby.w-1) {
                if(
                    (
                        (laby.get_visited(_y, _x) == 0) ||
                        (laby.get_visited(_y, _x) == 1 && laby.get_depth(y, x)+1 < laby.get_depth(_y, _x))
                    )
                  )
                {
                    laby.set_visited(y, x, _y, _x, f_y, f_x, laby.get_depth(y, x)+1);
                    monovector r; r.push_back(_y); r.push_back(_x); r.push_back(laby.get_priority(_y, _x));
                    openList.push_back(r);
                    r.clear();

                    if((_y == 0 || _y == laby.h-1 || _x == 0 || _x == laby.w-1) && (_y != f_y || _x != f_x)) {
                        int d = laby.get_depth(_y, _x);
                        openList.clear();
                        closedList.clear();
                        laby.reset();
                        return d;
                    }
                }
            }
            else { return laby.get_depth(y, x); };
        }

        appendClosedList(y, x, openList, closedList);
        dropOpenList(y, x, openList);

        int *yx = get_coords(openList);
        y = yx[0];
        x = yx[1];

        yx = get_nearest_goal(y, x, goals_t);
        f_y = yx[0];
        f_x = yx[1];

        delete yx;

    }
    int d = laby.get_depth(y, x);
    openList.clear();
    closedList.clear();
    laby.reset();
    return d;
}

int _abs(int num)
{
    if(num <= 0) return -num;
    else return num;
}

int* get_nearest_goal(int y, int x, bivector &goals_t)
{
    int min_dist = 1000000;
    int *f_coords = new int[2];
    for(size_t i = 1; i < goals_t.size(); i++) {
        if(_abs(y - goals_t[i][0]) + _abs(x - goals_t[i][1]) < min_dist) {
            min_dist = _abs(y - goals_t[i][0]) + _abs(x - goals_t[i][1]);
            f_coords[0] = goals_t[i][0];
            f_coords[1] = goals_t[i][1];
        }
    }

    return f_coords;
}

int* get_goals(int &goals, bivector &goals_t, laby_t &laby)
{
    for(int i = 1; i < laby.h - 1; i++) {
        if(laby.m_layout[i][0] == '.') {
            goals++;
            monovector t; t.push_back(i); t.push_back(0); goals_t.push_back(t);
            t.clear();
        }
        if(laby.m_layout[i][laby.w - 1] == '.') {
            goals++;
            monovector t; t.push_back(i); t.push_back(laby.w - 1); goals_t.push_back(t);
            t.clear();
        }
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < laby.w - 1; i++) {
        if(laby.m_layout[0][i] == '.') {
            goals++;
            monovector t; t.push_back(0); t.push_back(i); goals_t.push_back(t);
            t.clear();
        }
        if(laby.m_layout[laby.h - 1][i] == '.') {
            goals++;
            monovector t; t.push_back(laby.h - 1); t.push_back(i); goals_t.push_back(t);
            t.clear();
        }
    }

    return get_nearest_goal(laby.s_y, laby.s_x, goals_t);
}

int main()
{
    int *f_coords = new int[2];
    bivector goals_t;
    laby_t laby;

    f_coords = get_goals(goals, goals_t, laby);

    int min_path = wander(laby.s_y, laby.s_x, f_coords[0], f_coords[1], laby, goals_t);

    delete f_coords;

    std::cout << min_path << std::endl;
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I was too lazy to add comments, so tell me if they are needed.

Comment: This: `int *f_coords = new int[2];` just screams "I have no idea how to use C++". This is not Java don't use the language as if it was. Unless there is a good reason to use new you probably should not. Even if you use new you should never use `delete` as pointers life spans should be controlled by objects.

Comment: Clue 1: The variable `m_attr` should be declared as:  `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> m_attr(std::vector<std::vector<int>>(std::vector<int>(0, 4), w), h);` Done. All memory management correctly handled (unlike your code).

Answer (score 1):

Reviewing all of this is a fairly big task, so let me start with a few ideas and come back later if I have the time.

### Algorithmic considerations

As Sylvain pointed out in his answer to [your question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129584/a-shortest-path-algorithm-optimization-request), your heuristic is too simple and will underestimate the distance repeatedly and by substantial amounts. This will affect the running time of your algorithm to the point where something like a Dijkstra search may easily be better. For educational purposes, I think it would be best if you took Sylvain's other suggestion of implementing a reverse search from the exits to your startin location.

### Style

- Don't be a [three star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer). In this case in particular, hiding the additional information contained in your nodes in `m[][][0]` to `m[][][4]` makes it extremely difficult to read for anyone who hasn't spent hours writing it (i.e. you). Use a structured way of implementing your nodes like a `class` or a `struct`.
- Use standard names. 'monovector' and 'bivector' make sense only in your brain. Your 'monovector' is a 2D coordinate vector (it is NOT a good idea to make it an `std::vector`, more on that later!) - why not call it `vector2d` or `coordinate`? Your 'bivector' is a list of coordinates.

### Choice of data structures

Everything is a `vector` in your implementation. That's far from ideal

- A 2D coordinate vector always has exactly two elements. A C++ `std::vector` is designed to have a variable and arbitrary number of elements and is therefore not a good fit (I do agree that the name is confusing for someone coming to coding from a mathematical point of view).
- In the A* algorithm, you repeatedly need to take the cheapest (in terms of estimated remaining distance) element from the open list. It may be sensible to choose a data structure which is kept sorted automatically.

### Implementation issues

- If you were consistently working with a proper datatype for your nodes, you could easily get rid of the inefficient implementations of `appendClosedList` and `dropOpenList`. Both of those currently scan the entire lists, and all that while your program *knows* which node they have to remove/add - it's working on them at the very moment you call those functions!

### Memory management

As Loki Astari mentioned in the comments, most of these issues will automagically disappear with correct use of containers and [other relevant techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635882/raii-tutorial-for-c). It may still be worthwhile to know how to do things correctly 'your way', even if it isn't advisable to actually write code like that.

Now, it is not really a case of finding "just a stupid memory leak" in your code, practically everything in there leaks or does error-prone things.
Just consider, as an example,

```
    int *yx = get_coords(openList);
    y = yx[0];
    x = yx[1];

    yx = get_nearest_goal(y, x, goals_t);
    f_y = yx[0];
    f_x = yx[1];

    delete yx;
```

First of all, allocation is handled by the callee and deallocation by the caller, which is (imho) intransparent and error-prone. Then, you're reusing `yx`, the memory allocated in `get_coords` always leaks. Additionally, you allocate memory in `get_nearest_goal` with `new[]`, then deallocate it with `delete`.
Furthermore, your `reset()` function is [completely broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601375/delete-multidimensional-arrays).

Answer (score 0):

I remember two optimization from my own implementation of the A* algorithm.

- Use only one list and give an Closed/Opened flag to your item. Then instead of removing/adding items from one list to another, simply toggle the flag.
- Use a map / multimap instead of vector. Sort them with a custom comparator. Then instead of doing linear searches in vectors, the map will quickly find what you need it its sorted tree.

Comment: But if you just toggle flags, you either have to scan the entire list in each step or insert the nodes obtained from the extension at a middle point in the list, no? I don't quite see how this is more efficient.